# How to use a Name rather than OID in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sharp-snmp

Good day,

I am trying to figure out this code from sharp-snmp samples.

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/blob/master/Samples/VB.NET/snmpset/Program.vb

I am using the vb.net SET sample.

```
Public Sub New(id As Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.ObjectIdentifier, data As Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.ISnmpData)
    Member of Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Variable

Public Sub New(id As UInteger(), data As Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.ISnmpData)
    Member of Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Variable
```

Is my Name syntax just wrong, or is it that it must be an OID integer? When I use the OID it runs, when I use the name it dies.

```
System_Operation_Mode.0 'name
1.3.6.1.4.1.21703.100.1.1.0 'oid
```

This is the part of the SET sample where it dies at the asterix ** at the bottom of the code.
Extra(i) is filled out with the above Name instead of the OID.

```
    ReDim args(3)
        args(0) = "192.168.45.5" 'IP Address
        args(1) = NetworkConfig.addrModeStringCommand 'command string name System_Operation_Mode.0
        args(2) = "i" 'tell it what data type you are sending
        args(3) = NetworkConfig.StaticMode 'mode you want from the IPNetwork, in this case static


        Dim p As OptionSet = New OptionSet().Add("c:", "Community name, (default is public)", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                                  If v IsNot Nothing Then
                                                                                                      community = v
                                                                                                  End If
                                                                                              End Sub) _
                                            .Add("l:", "Security level, (default is noAuthNoPriv)", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                                        If v.ToUpperInvariant() = "NOAUTHNOPRIV" Then
                                                                                                            level = Levels.Reportable
                                                                                                        ElseIf v.ToUpperInvariant() = "AUTHNOPRIV" Then
                                                                                                            level = Levels.Authentication Or Levels.Reportable
                                                                                                        ElseIf v.ToUpperInvariant() = "AUTHPRIV" Then
                                                                                                            level = Levels.Authentication Or Levels.Privacy Or Levels.Reportable
                                                                                                        Else
                                                                                                            Throw New ArgumentException("no such security mode: " & v)
                                                                                                        End If
                                                                                                    End Sub) _
                                            .Add("a:", "Authentication method (MD5 or SHA)", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                                 authentication = v
                                                                                             End Sub) _
                                            .Add("A:", "Authentication passphrase", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                        authPhrase = v
                                                                                    End Sub) _
                                            .Add("x:", "Privacy method", Sub(v As String)
                                                                             privacy = v
                                                                         End Sub) _
                                            .Add("X:", "Privacy passphrase", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                 privPhrase = v
                                                                             End Sub) _
                                            .Add("u:", "Security name", Sub(v As String)
                                                                            user = v
                                                                        End Sub) _
                                            .Add("C:", "Context name", Sub(v As String)
                                                                           contextName = v
                                                                       End Sub) _
                                            .Add("h|?|help", "Print this help information.", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                                 showHelp__1 = v IsNot Nothing
                                                                                             End Sub) _
                                            .Add("V", "Display version number of this application.", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                                         showVersion = v IsNot Nothing
                                                                                                     End Sub) _
                                            .Add("d", "Display message dump", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                  dump = True
                                                                              End Sub) _
                                            .Add("t:", "Timeout value (unit is second).", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                              timeout = Integer.Parse(v) * 1000
                                                                                          End Sub) _
                                            .Add("r:", "Retry count (default is 0)", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                         retry = Integer.Parse(v)
                                                                                     End Sub) _
                                            .Add("v:", "SNMP version (1, 2, and 3 are currently supported)", Sub(v As String)
                                                                                                                 Select Case Integer.Parse(v)
                                                                                                                     Case 1
                                                                                                                         version = VersionCode.V1
                                                                                                                         Exit Select
                                                                                                                     Case 2
                                                                                                                         version = VersionCode.V2
                                                                                                                         Exit Select
                                                                                                                     Case 3
                                                                                                                         version = VersionCode.V3
                                                                                                                         Exit Select
                                                                                                                     Case Else
                                                                                                                         Throw New ArgumentException("no such version: " & v)
                                                                                                                 End Select
                                                                                                             End Sub)

        If args.Length = 0 Then
            ShowHelp(p)
            Return
        End If

        Dim extra As List(Of String)
        Try
            extra = p.Parse(args)
        Catch ex As OptionException
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Return
        End Try

        If showHelp__1 Then
            ShowHelp(p)
            Return
        End If

        If (extra.Count - 1) Mod 3 <> 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("invalid variable number: " & extra.Count)
            Return
        End If

        If showVersion Then
            Console.WriteLine(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version)
            Return
        End If

        Dim ip As IPAddress
        Dim parsed As Boolean = IPAddress.TryParse(extra(0), ip)
        If Not parsed Then
            For Each address As IPAddress In Dns.GetHostAddresses(extra(0))
                If address.AddressFamily <> AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                ip = address
                Exit For
            Next

            If ip Is Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("invalid host or wrong IP address found: " & extra(0))
                Return
            End If
        End If

        Try
            Dim vList As New List(Of Variable)()
            Dim i As Integer = 1
            While i < extra.Count
                Dim type As String = extra(i + 1)
                If type.Length <> 1 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid type string: " & type)
                    Return
                End If

                Dim data As ISnmpData

                Select Case type(0)
                    Case "i"c
                        data = New Integer32(Integer.Parse(extra(i + 2)))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "u"c
                        data = New Gauge32(UInteger.Parse(extra(i + 2)))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "t"c
                        data = New TimeTicks(UInteger.Parse(extra(i + 2)))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "a"c
                        data = New IP(IPAddress.Parse(extra(i + 2)).GetAddressBytes())
                        Exit Select
                    Case "o"c
                        data = New ObjectIdentifier(extra(i + 2))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "x"c
                        data = New OctetString(ByteTool.Convert(extra(i + 2)))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "s"c
                        data = New OctetString(extra(i + 2))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "d"c
                        data = New OctetString(ByteTool.ConvertDecimal(extra(i + 2)))
                        Exit Select
                    Case "n"c
                        data = New Null()
                        Exit Select
                    Case Else
                        Console.WriteLine("unknown type string: " & type(0))
                        Return
                End Select

                Dim test As New Variable(*New ObjectIdentifier(extra(i))*, data)
                vList.Add(test)
                i = i + 3
            End While
```

I have been using using the "Name" instead of the "OID" is there a way to change so it can read either, or have them converted? Or will I have to go back use the OIDs?

Comment: I don't think you shared enough code to reveal what exactly was the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more from the code. It is one of your samples from the vb.net SET. I've changed nothing except filling out the arguments. I am still learning how it works.

Comment: Users of the open source #SNMP Library have to use numerical OIDs when initializing `ObjectIdentifier` objects. If you want to use textual names, then you need a MIB document parser, which is available as part of #SNMP Pro, https://pro.sharpsnmp.com/getting-started/assembly-features.html That's a commercial product.

Comment: OK, I will use the OIDs. Thanks.